# Grails seems to have wrong hibernate dependency

Tags: hibernate, grails, dependency-management

I am upgrading my Grails project from version 2.3.5 to grails 2.4.0.
Since I have multiple instances of my application in production, I am doing this upgrade in a git branch. 
Because I have to solve issues on the 2.3.5 version of my app, I sometimes have to switch back to that version.
Suddenly the 1.3.5 version doesn't run anymore:

```
    BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/cache/spi/RegionFactory
```

When I searched for this error I found out this part belongs to the Hibernate 4.3.5.2 dependency, which is NOT in the BuildConfig.groovy for the 2.3.5 version (but it is in the 2.4.0 version).
When I run `grails dependency-report` it shows this:

```
    +--- org.grails.plugins:hibernate4:4.3.5.2
|    \--- org.hibernate:hibernate-ehcache:4.3.5.Final
|         \--- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging-annotations:1.2.0.Beta1
|    \--- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:5.0.3.Final
|         \--- com.fasterxml:classmate:1.0.0
|    \--- net.sf.ehcache:ehcache-core:2.4.8
|    \--- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:3.1.0.GA 
|    \--- org.grails:grails-datastore-gorm-hibernate4:3.1.0.RELEASE
|         \--- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:4.0.4.Final
|    \--- javax.validation:validation-api:1.1.0.Final
```

While my BuildConfig looks like this:

```
grails.servlet.version = "3.0" // Change depending on target container compliance (2.5 or 3.0)
grails.project.class.dir = "target/classes"
grails.project.test.class.dir = "target/test-classes"
grails.project.test.reports.dir = "target/test-reports"
grails.project.work.dir = "target/work"
grails.project.target.level = 1.6
grails.project.source.level = 1.6
grails.project.war.file = "target/${grails.util.Environment.current.name}-${appVersion}.war"
grails.project.dependency.resolver = "maven"

grails.tomcat.nio=true

grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
// inherit Grails' default dependencies
inherits("global") {
    // uncomment to disable ehcache
    // excludes 'ehcache'
}
log "warn" // log level of Ivy resolver, either 'error', 'warn', 'info', 'debug' or 'verbose'
repositories {
    inherits true // Whether to inherit repository definitions from plugins
    grailsHome()
        mavenLocal()

    grailsPlugins()
    grailsCentral()

    // uncomment the below to enable remote dependency resolution
    // from public Maven repositories
    mavenCentral()
    //mavenRepo "http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org"
    mavenRepo "http://repository.codehaus.org"
        mavenRepo "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/"

    //for export plugin 1.6
    mavenRepo "http://repo.grails.org/grails/core"
}
dependencies {
    // specify dependencies here under either 'build', 'compile', 'runtime', 'test' or 'provided' scopes eg.
    //       runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.16'

    runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.21'
    runtime 'com.github.groovy-wslite:groovy-wslite:0.7.1'

    test 'junit:junit:4.11'
    test 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-all:1.3'
//      runtime "org.jggug.kobo:kobo-commons:0.2"

    //for export plugin 1.6
    compile 'commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:1.8.3'
}
plugins {
    build ":tomcat:7.0.47"

    // plugins for the compile step
            compile ":scaffolding:2.0.1"
    compile ':cache:1.1.1'
    compile ':mail:1.0.1', {
        excludes 'spring-test'
      }
        compile ":quartz2:2.1.6.2"
        compile ":csv:0.3.1"
        compile ":export:1.6"
//      compile ":jasper:1.2.1"
        compile ":jasper:1.6.1"
        compile ":spring-security-core:1.2.7.3"

        // plugins needed at runtime but not for compilation
    runtime ":hibernate:3.6.10.6" // or ":hibernate4:4.1.11.1"
    runtime ":database-migration:1.3.8"
    runtime ":jquery:1.10.2"
    compile ":jquery-ui:1.10.3"
            runtime ":resources:1.2.1"      
        compile ":events-push:1.0.M7"
//      compile ":ajax-uploader:1.1"

        // Uncomment these (or add new ones) to enable additional resources capabilities
        //runtime ":zipped-resources:1.0"
        //runtime ":cached-resources:1.0"
        //runtime ":yui-minify-resources:0.1.4"

        compile ':cache:1.0.0'
    }
}
```

As you can see, no hibernate4:4.3.5.2 there. 
I tried to delete my .m2 directory, my .grails directory to refresh the dependencies, but it didn't work.

However, on my laptop I haven't used the grails 2.4.0 branch yet and everything works fine there! That dependency graph only shows the expected hibernate 3.6.10.6 dependency.

Has anyone any clue how this is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your answer Jeff, but that wasn't the solution (we always `clean` before we run).

It turned out the issue was in a plugin we created ourselves (not displayed in the BuildConfig.groovy above). We also upgraded those to grails 2.4.0. and this added the Hibernate4 4.3.5.2.
So when I switch back to the 2.3.5 version of my app, I also need to switch back to the grails 2.3.5 version of the plugin, of course!

Answer (score 1):

If you are switching back and forth between git branches in the same workspace should remove the `target` directory and rebuild your code with the version of Grails that corresponds to the branch you recently switched to.  I cannot say for sure with just the information provided here, but depending on some other factors that may solve your problem.